# Left outer join in Linq

Tags: linq, outer-join

**I know there is tons of posts on this but they are all about specific problems that I didn't understand what is left, right and anything**

I have 2 lists: left and right. I need to select all elements in left that are not in right.

```
List<T> left = GetLeft();
List<T> right = GetRight();

IEnumerable result = // Have no idea
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a join at all... that sounds like:

```
var result = left.Except(right);
```

Comment: Looks like thats it, I'm too used to SQL

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I found.

Find all customers without purchases:

SQL:

> ```
>    Select c.Name from Customers c             
>    Left Outer Join Purchases p on c.customerid=p.customerid 
>    where p.price is null
> ```

LINQ:

> ```
>    from c in Customers
>    join p in Purchases on c.customerid=p.customerid into custPurchases
>    from cp in custPurchases.DefaultIfEmpty()
>    where cp==null
>    select new
>    {
>    cc.Name
>    }
> ```